# What happens when C is only partly within the vector field?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals

So I have the following question where $$\vec{G}=(x,y)/\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}$$ is a vector field.
I have to calculate the line integral for $$\int_{\mathrm{C}}\vec{G}\, d\vec{r}\, $$ where $C$ is the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}=1$. 
I know that $\vec{G}$ has the domain $x^2+y^2 \gt 1,$ (meaning that the circle with radius 1 is not part of the domain) and the ellipse has radius 2 with x-component and 3 for y-component.
I have calculated param $x=2cost$ and $y=3sint$ where $0\le t\le 2\pi$.
So does this mean that only a part of the ellipse is within $\vec{G}$?

How do I calculate the line integral in this case?

Comment: Are you sure the ellipse is not in the domain?  Seems like it surrounds the circle so you are okay.

Comment: How is field $\vec{F}$ related to $\vec{G}$?

Comment: @NitinUniyal it's supposed to be $\vec{G}$ my bad.

Comment: @Randall only part of it is in the domain since the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ with radius 1 is not part of the domain and the ellipse has radius 2 and 3 so I thought everything within( including the circle with radius 1) are part of the ellipse . Or am I wrong? How do I calculate the line integral?

Comment: The ellipse is a curve, not a solid.  That’s why it’s often called $C$.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to parametrize this, nor do you need Green's theorem.  By usual integration tricks, your function $\vec{G}$ has a potential:
$$
g(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}.
$$
You can check that $\vec{G} = \nabla g$, and this is valid over a domain that "encloses" your ellipse in a nice, legal way.  Now use the fundamental theorem:
$$
\int_C \vec{G} \cdot d\vec{r} = g(2,0) -g(2,0) = 0
$$
as $C$ is a closed curve.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If it helps, you can upvote and/or accept the answer. @18929371

Answer (score 0):

The ellipse $C: x^2/4+y^2/9=1$ is well within the field $\vec{G}=\frac{x\hat i+y\hat j}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}}$ which is defined for the exterior of circle $x^2+y^2=1$ so you can easily evaluate the line integral using *Green's theorem*(after making it simply connected using a two-way cut).

$\int_C\vec{G}.\vec{dr}=\int\int_R curl(\vec{G})dR$

where $R$ is the region bounded by ellipse on $xy-$plane.

Comment: I have not yet learned about Green's theorem, it is in the next chapter. Is there no way to solve it without green's?

Comment: The domain is not simply connected here, though.

Comment: @Randall...yes that can be done with a two-way cut in $R$. Though it hardly matters computationally as $curl(\vec{F})=0$.

Comment: @18929371...Then use parametrization of ellipse but I am afraid that is too much time taking.

Comment: @NitinUniyal you mean that I could just calculate it like usual? don't bother about the $x^2+y^2 \gt 1$ part?

Comment: As long as you are not using Green's theorem you can compute it as usual due to the fact that the curve $C$ is under the influence of field $\vec{G}$.